# INotifyPropertyChanged in UserControl

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have a custom control which is inherited from TextBox control.
I would like to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in my custom control.

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

My problem is when I try to raised a PropertyChanged event the PropertyChanged event handler is always null.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: It doesnt work like you did. Just create an extra class and implement Notification Interface there and apply this class to the DataContext of the UserControl. And it will work like you need.

Answer (score 15):

> the PropertyChanged event handler is alwas null.

This will always be true until something subscribes to the `PropertyChanged` event.

Typically, if you're making a custom control, however, you wouldn't use `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  In this scenario, you'd make a [Custom Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903933%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead.  Normally, the dependency objects (ie: controls) will all use Dependency Properties, and INPC is used by the classes which become the `DataContext` of these objects.  This allows the binding system to work properly.

Answer (score 11):

The PropertyChanged event is used by UI code, but not in that sense you are writing. Controls never implement INPC (short for INotifyPropertyChanged), they are bound to object that *have implemented* INPC. This way certain UI properties, e.g. the **Text** property on the TextBox control is bound to a property on such class. This is the basis of MVVM architecture.

Example, you would write the following XAML code:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtBox" Text="{Binding Title}" />
```

And you set the data context for TextBlock (or any of its ancestors, DataContext is propagated) in the code in the following manner:

```
txtBox.DataContext = new Movie {Title = "Titanic"};
```

And now for the class itself:

```
public class Movie : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            if (_title == value) return;

            _title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you change the `Title property`, whether in the code or via other binding, UI will be automatically refreshed. Here's more information about [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0) and [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern).

Comment: This is updating the control whenever the data changes, but I assume the OP is trying to implement two-way binding where the data source is automatically updated by the UserControl. Presumably there is some way to notify that the user control has updated the property, but I haven't found that yet.

Answer (score 5):

Do it like I said in the comments.
It doesnt work like you did. Just create an extra class and implement `Notification Interface` there and apply this class to the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`. And it will work like you need.

```
 public partial class W3 : UserControl
    {
        WeatherViewModel model = new WeatherViewModel();

        public W3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = model;
        }

        public void UpdateUI(List<WeatherDetails> data, bool isNextDays)
        {
            model.UpdateUI(data, isNextDays);
        }
    }

    class WeatherViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {     

        public void UpdateUI(List<WeatherDetails> data, bool isNextDays)
        {
            List<WeatherDetails> weatherInfo = data;
            if (weatherInfo.Count != 0)
            {
                CurrentWeather = weatherInfo.First();
                if (isNextDays)
                    Forecast = weatherInfo.Skip(1).ToList();
            }
        }

        private List<WeatherDetails> _forecast = new List<WeatherDetails>();

        public List<WeatherDetails> Forecast
        {
            get { return _forecast; }
            set
            {
                _forecast = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Forecast");
            }
        }

        private WeatherDetails _currentWeather = new WeatherDetails();

        public WeatherDetails CurrentWeather
        {
            get { return _currentWeather; }
            set
            {
                _currentWeather = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentWeather");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know this is from 2016, but I have found mixed results on whether or not your user controls in WPF should contain a ViewModel inside of themselves. What is the best practice?