# How to use RichTextBlock.HasOverflowContent in WP 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm using `RichTextBlock` in Windows Phone 8.1 RT to show some text. To limit the size of the text that can be displayed at a given time, I'm setting the `MaxLines` property. Whenever the text exceeds this value, it's trimmed.

Now, I have a hyperlink at the bottom of the `RichTextBlock` that should get visible whenever the text is trimmed. For detecting if the text was trimmed, I'm using the `RichTextBlock.HasOverflowContent`. If this property is set to true, I set to visibility of the hyperlink to visible so the user can click on it and see the full untrimmed message.

But there is a problem with this solution. Sometimes the text is trimmed, but the property is still false and the hyperlink stays hidden.

I don't really know how to use the above property to detect content trimming. What's the correct way to use this? I'm doing the processing in the `Loaded` event of the `RichTextBlock`:

```
private void RichTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var richtextblock = sender as RichTextBlock;

    // Check if the content of the RichTextBlock was trimmed.
    if (richtextblock.HasOverflowContent)
    {
        // Prepare hyperlink and set visibility to visible.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking the value of HasOverflowContent when the RichTextBlock is loaded, why don't you try to bind the visibility property of the hyperlink to the HasOverflowContent property (using a Boolean To Visibility converter of course)?

Comment: I'm using the `RichTextBlock` in a user control, and cannot implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to bind the property to UI acc. to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466216/inotifypropertychanged-in-usercontrol.

Comment: You do not need INotifyPropertyChanged. Just give the RichTextBox a name, then bind using ElementName: {Binding ElementName=richTextBlock, Path=HasOverflowContent, Converter=...}"

Comment: the visibility part works fine now, thanks to the binding. But I also do some processing in the `if` block (text formatting using `Run` and `Underline` for hyperlink creation). I don't want to do that processing for each textblock, but only for the ones where the text is trimmed. Where should I ideally access `HasOverflowContent`, because the `Loaded` event gives incorrect values sometimes?

Comment: Check for example this link for a class allowing you to subscribe to changes in a DependencyProperty: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2013/04/21/detecting-dependency-property-changes-in-winrt/